# Concise way of saying "harder than we were thinking"

Tags: word-choice, academic-writing

I am writing the following sentence in a research article:

> The authors investigated the feasibility of XXX; we find that this direction, though look promising, is much harder than we thought.

I am hesitated to use the phase "much harder than we thought". It seems wordy; what could be a proper and more concise replacement in this sentence?

Comment: Harder than expected.

Comment: '... much harder than expected'. Saves 1 letter and 1 space (but sounds more professional). /// 'look' should be 'it looks/looked' or 'looking'.

Comment: The standard way of saying this would be "... proved harder than expected". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proved+harder+than+expected&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproved%20harder%20than%20expected%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cproved%20harder%20than%20expected%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Comparative Research is Harder Than We Thought: Regional Differences in Experts’ Understanding of Electoral Integrity Questions" - title of [Cambridge paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-analysis/article/comparative-research-is-harder-than-we-thought-regional-differences-in-experts-understanding-of-electoral-integrity-questions/E3CC3AC2720DF4EEB19384AD16E9FE3C)

Comment: You can also consider leaving the "than we thought" part out. "... this direction looks promising, but it's very hard" or "... very complicated"

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> We found that though this direction looked promising, it was harder than we expected

You could also exclude the middle and write:

> We found that this direction was harder than we expected

or

> This direction proved to be harder than we expected

Answer (score 0):

I'd say either:

> The authors investigated the feasibility of XXX; although this direction looked promising, it was not trivial.

or

> The authors investigated the feasibility of XXX; although this direction looked promising, it proved harder than anticipated.

I wouldn't use "we", but that might be different in your field.